# Reconfigure replicas set with bash script

Tags: bash, mongodb, replication

There is a replica set and it would be create if the set could automatically scale reads.
Sometimes some new member would be added or removed. I try to make it in a bash script.

```
set_name="gomble"
port_client=27072 # primary node in a replica set
port_newbie=28888
# generating a new configuration file by python script
config_file=$(python -c "import new_cfg_v2 as cfg; print cfg.getConfig('$hostname',$port_client,'$hostname',$port_newbie,'$set_name')")
```

config_file looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "gomble",
    "version" : 4,
    "members" : [
        {
            "host" : "alehandro-VirtualBox:27072",
            "_id" : 0
        },
        {
            "host" : "alehandro-VirtualBox:27077",
            "_id" : 1
        },
        {
            "host" : "alehandro-VirtualBox:27777",
            "_id" : 3
        },
        {
            "host" : "alehandro-VirtualBox:28888",
            "_id" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Than following command is executed:

```
echo $(/usr/bin/mongo --port $port_client --eval "rs.reconfig('$config_file')")
```

OUTPUT: MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5 connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27072/test [object Object]

But the the new member with _id:4 is not added???

The reconfiguration could be made with `rs.add()`, `rs.remove()`, but I hope that it could be done with `rs.reconfig()` also.

Comment: Is mongo aware of the full path of python? it might not know what Python is, try providing full path. Also could you try running your script with bash -x script.sh ? And post the output. There might be a hint there are to why it's happening. Also, why are you echoing out the subshell $(/usr/bin/mongo --port $port_client --eval "rs.reconfig('$config_file')") ?

Comment: Did you also increment the version number - if not it wont accept the configuration.

Comment: I've tried with incrementing the version number and without. It doesn't mate if you pass the right version number or even without number. MongoDB sets the version number according the last version number plus one. I've tested it with version numbers in Python and it works. The line with `echo` was exported in Python and there all work fine.

Comment: Later I try to post the output after calling the `echo $(/usr/bin/mongo --port $port_client --eval "rs.reconfig('$config_file')")`. It might be helpful for somebody who tries to reconfigure in upstart file a replicas set.